# FileNotFound error / reading PDF Files with PyPDF2 and os.listdir()

Tags: python, pypdf

I have the following script to merge a couple of PDFs together:

```
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os

inputs = sys.argv[1]
list = os.listdir(inputs)

merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in list:
     merger.append(pdf)

merger.write('merged.pdf')
print('All done')
```

The folder with the files is in a different directory than the running script, thus I inserted the full path.

Upon running like so from the terminal, `python3 pdf-merger.py /Users/user/Documents/pdf_list`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf-merger.py", line 11, in <module>
    merger.append(pdf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyPDF2/merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyPDF2/merger.py", line 114, in merge
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'card.pdf'
```

I also tried with an alternative method:

```
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os

inputs = sys.argv[1]
list = [os.path.join(inputs,a) for a in os.listdir(inputs)]

merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in list:
     merger.append(pdf)

merger.write('merged.pdf')
print('All done')
```

This time I get a `PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file`, no matter what file it is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There was a hidden `.DS_Store` file in the directory which corrupted the script.

Ignoring it with `if pdf.endswith('.pdf')` resolved the issue!